# How should we handle questions whose answers change often?

Tags: discussion, questions

There may be a global StackExchange answer for this that I am unaware of, but how should we handle questions whose answers would change periodically?

For instance:

- League rules that may change every season
- Player or league statistics that *could* change every day (these may be considered off-topic already, not sure)
- etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This has been covered on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47984/13531) (unsurprisingly, since programming languages/libraries change so often).

> **Answers:**
>
> If you have the power, edit the existing answer and update it. If you do not have edit privilege, write a new one and add a comment to the existing one, pointing to yours. Ask others to merge them.
>
> **Questions:**
>
> Edit, if you can. If not, ask your own, link to the other question, explain why you ask again and ask a moderator, if he can merge the questions.

That said, I think most statistics questions are too ephemeral to really work here; and those that aren't (e.g. "Who has the most receiving touchdowns in NFL history?") are usually easily looked up, so I don't know that they're worth hosting either.