# What is our current policy on statistics questions?

Tags: discussion

A new user has asked these two questions

https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/who-is-the-best-t20-bowler-in-terms-of-overall-economy-rate

[How many times have the team batting first declared innings and then lost the match by innings?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/how-many-times-have-the-team-batting-first-declared-innings-and-then-lost-the-ma)

I've found some discussion in previous meta posts on how to treat these sorts of questions, such as

[How should we handle questions whose answers change often?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-should-we-handle-questions-whose-answers-change-often)

There doesn't seem to be a clear consensus that I can find on meta as to how to deal with these questions. It probably comes down to a judgement call on each question, since one like this

[What is the longest winning streak in tennis with a player not dropping a single game](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/what-is-the-longest-winning-streak-in-tennis-with-a-player-not-dropping-a-single)

is similar but perhaps not as bad. I'd suggest we should generally consider questions that could be answered by a simple search of a sports specific stats/records site as not constructive, but allow some discretion if the question has some interesting aspects. This isn't covered in the FAQ though, so as it stands it would be a little harsh on new users to close such questions. I don't think they ultimately add very much to the site though.

Comment: Interesting. One of our [mods](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/13/527) share a similar view. That raises the question...what types of statistics questions should be covered? Some are acceptable (sabermetrics in baseball), but we, the community, is discovering that other such statistics questions do not...

Comment: Some of these statistics questions (especially the ones you refer to) fall under `trivia`. It was determined during a [quality evaluation](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/260/sports-trivia-evaluation) last year that such questions are on-topic for this site.

Comment: How about [this](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/which-is-more-likely-to-result-in-a-goal-a-penalty-shot-or-a-power-play) statistics question? A noticeable trend occurs when evaluating several seasons.

Comment: @edmastermind29 the hockey question is VERY interesting in my opinion, I would hate question like that to be branded as off-topic here.

Comment: @posdef exactly

Comment: I agree, that's a great question. It's clear then that the issue is not 'the question contains statistics' that is the problem with some other questions. It's probably more of a 'too localised' issue, so that good question covers an interesting and fundamental questions, whereas the other questions I pointed to addressed trivial edge cases and had very limited scope. It's clear that 'statistics questions are bad' is too simplistic. I'll have a think about how to succinctly describe the 'bad' stats questions to not whack the good ones.

Comment: @Bogdanovist There is a fine line, but your point is clearly made. It is also verbalized [here](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/358/527), and we need to develop a solution that promotes quality questions in this area.