# Double Standards in Questions Containing Resource Requests

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons

A few days ago I've asked a question, which I [deleted](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/any-website-showing-number-of-headed-goals-by-teams) after a while as it was closed as *off-topic* and it wasn't possible to improve it because anyways under current rules it would be still considered off-topic. This was the question:

> **Any website showing number of headed goals by teams**
>
> In recent months Real Madrid C.F. players, especially Sergio Ramos, were showing an outstanding performance in set pieces. So I am curious now how many headed goals they and other teams have scored throughout this season.
>
> A deep google search didn't return me any website showing statistics
>   of headed goals by teams. So the question is: do you know such a web
>   resource?

[The help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the site clearly states that:

> Sports Stack Exchange is NOT a forum. Some kinds of questions should
>   NOT be asked here:
>
> - ...
> - Requests for sources/research

All good, but then shortly after I saw [this positively voted question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11949/tennis-statistics-by-sets-and-games) in the questions feed, which requests...

> ...a resource where author could find the results for some specific historic tennis games...

Now I'm curious why some questions containing resource requests are very welcome, whereas the others are closed as off-topic? Even the ones with resource requests for a very scarce resource that is very hard to find in the web, so give it some time, it could turn into valuable question for others seeking relevant information.

I am dissatisfied both with the fact that those type of questions are labeled off-topic and that some are accepted by users very well, whereas the others (like mine) are being downvoted.

Comment: +1 for pointing out an inconsistency. I believe this [meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583) is related. The question  "Where can I find stats on this?" was addressed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You were not "forced" to delete anything. You *chose* to do so.
2. "Protected by Community" doesn't actually mean very much - it's an automatic response by the SE system after two spam answers were posted on the question on Tuesday.
3. Yeah, that's not a great question. It should probably have been closed - but it's not worth getting stressed about.

Comment: "On hold" isn't the death knell for a question. You had the option to improve the question and make it on-topic; however you decided, of your own free will, not to try and improve it but instead to press "delete".

Comment: @gdrt94: Perhaps you meant "in effect" then?

Comment: Writing "in fact" does not make it fact.

Comment: But you still willingly deleted it. If the deletion was really unwilling, would you like the question to be undeleted so you can try to improve it?

Comment: Have you noticed that the question you noted as also being off-topic has now been closed appropriately? Thank you for pointing that out, but going on about this is now getting unnecessary.

Comment: Community ♦ is **not** the same thing as the community. Automatic protections have no relationship to topicality. Sports is just one of several sites using the Community bumps to identify old questions that are no longer suitable, then removing them. You need to understand just how long Stack Exchange, Sports in particular, has been going, and how far the standards have shifted in that time.

Comment: @Nij This was actually a slightly different case in that the question was automatically protected by the Community user after it got spammed, rather than just the "regular" bumping to the homepage (which wouldn't have happened for that question as it had an upvoted accepted answer). But your point in general is still valid :-)